# Javascript - how to avoid multiple if condition checks when checking if object has a property?

Tags: javascript, object

How can I avoid such long if conditions?

```
if (typeof window.checkoutConfig.shipping !== "undefined") {
    if (typeof window.checkoutConfig.shipping.rules !== "undefined") {
        if (typeof window.checkoutConfig.shipping.rules.express !== "undefined") {
            if (typeof window.checkoutConfig.shipping.rules.express.express_note !== "undefined") {
                this.expressNote(window.checkoutConfig.shipping.rules.express.express_note || "");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a method which I can use instead, for example (pseudo code): `isset(window.checkoutConfig.shipping.rules.express.express_note)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just *try*.

```
try {
  this.expressNote(window.checkoutConfig.shipping.rules.express.express_note || "");
} catch (e) {
  // meh
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

It will allow you to write:

```js
window.checkoutConfig.shipping?.rules?.express?.express_note
```

As mentionned in the comments, you may want to use [babel](https://babeljs.io/) to make it compatible with older browsers.

```js
var a = {};
a?.b?.c
```

will be compiled as:

```js
var _a$b;
var a = {};
a == null ? void 0 : (_a$b = a.b) == null ? void 0 : _a$b.c;
```

Comment: C'mon I was about to answer with this but you beat me to it

Comment: This only protects against `null` and `undefined` values - logic that depends on `typeof` of `instanceof` still needs more complicated guard logic.

Comment: Worth noting that you'd have a bad time if you are trying to support browsers older than 2020.

Comment: Is there also an alternative which is supported by older browsers?

Comment: Of course you can use babel to make to compatible with older browsers

Comment: @GaetanC., nice, i did not know about babel. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

ES2020 introduced **optional chaining**, to prevent errors like `Cannot read property of undefined`. Just add a ? before each optional property:
`window.checkOutConfig.shipping?.rules?.express?.express_note`
will return `undefined` if the property does not exist but the property's value if it does.