# Avoid recurring 'if' verification to check if an object has property

Tags: javascript, object, properties, conditional-statements, hasownproperty

I **do know** how to check if a property exists (`hasOwnProperty`, `in`, `!== undefined`, etc).

But I don't know how to avoid to perform an action on this property if it doesn't exist.

Is there a solution to avoid the `if` (`property && action` in my case) verification each time ?

Similar question : [Javascript - how to avoid multiple if condition checks when checking if object has a property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64553427/javascript-how-to-avoid-multiple-if-condition-checks-when-checking-if-object-h) Not really relevant in my case

```js
const myFunction1 = myFunction2 = () => {};
const generateElement = (p) => {
  let div = document.createElement(p.tag);
  p.classes && (div.className = p.classes);
  p.style && (div.style.cssText = p.style);
  p.content && (div.innerHTML = p.content);
  p.appendIn && p.appendIn.appendChild(div);
  p.attribs && Object.entries(p.attribs).forEach((y) => {
    div.setAttribute(y[0], y[1]);
  });
  p.events && Object.entries(p.events).forEach((y) => {
    div.addEventListener(y[0], y[1], false);
  });
  return div
}

var newElem = generateElement({
  tag: 'div',
  classes: 'mydiv',
  id: 'id42',
  content: 'Hello world!',
  style: 'background:#ccc',
  attribs: {
    'tabindex': 0,
    'title': 'Title #1'
  },
  events: {
    'click': myFunction1,
    'mouseout': myFunction2
  },
  appendIn: document.body
});
```

Comment: Consider using [*Object.keys*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) then iterate over the keys so you'll only access the own properties.

Comment: Also a simple if, saves the && and is much more readable

Answer (score 0):

If you have the right JS version you could set defaults and use the null coalescing opperator https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator

```
//Empty strings as default will keep the functionality the same    
div.className = p.classes ?? '';
//use empty objects where needed
Object.entries(p.events ?? {}).forEach(...)
```

Comment: How does this handle the case for `p.events && Object.entries(p.events).forEach(...)`?

Comment: Pretty much the same Object.entries(p.events ?? {}).forEach(...)

Comment: So worth including the different pattern in the answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using *Object.keys* similarly to how you've used *Object.entries* and create an *addProp* function to deal with each kind of property and value using *switch*, that way you only deal with properties that exist in the *p* object and can ignore unknown properties too, e.g.

```js
const generateElement = (p) => {

  if (!p.tag) return;

  let node = document.createElement(p.tag);
  if (!node) return;

  let props = Object.keys(p);
  props.forEach(prop => addProp(node, prop, p[prop]));
}

function addProp(el, prop, value) {
  switch (prop) {
    case 'appendIn':
      value.appendChild(el);
      break;
    case 'attribs':
      Object.entries(value).forEach(([p, v]) => el.setAttribute(p, v));
      break;
    case 'classes':
      el.className = value;
      break;
    case 'content':
      el.innerHTML = value;
      break;
    case 'events':
      Object.entries(value).forEach(([p, v]) => el.addEventListener(p, v, false));
      break;
    case 'id' :
      el.id = value;
      break;
    case 'style':
      el.style.cssText = value;
      break;
    case 'tag' : // Already done
      break;
    default :
      console.log(`Unexpected property: ${prop}`);
  }
  return el;
}

var newElem = generateElement({
  tag: 'div',
  classes: 'mydiv',
  id: 'id42',
  content: 'Hello world!',
  style: 'background:#ccc;color:red',
  attribs: {
    'tabindex': 0,
    'title': 'Title #1'
  },
  events: {
    'click': () => console.log('click'),
    'mouseout': () => console.log('mouseout')
  },
  appendIn: document.body,
  foo: 'bar'
});
```

You could do a similar thing with *Object.entries* using either *forEach* or *for..of*:

```
let node = document.createElement(p.tag);
for (let [prop, value] of Object.entries(p)) {
   addProp(node, prop, value);
}
```

whatever.